# What is the term for a client that does things on behalf of the server?

Tags: terminology, networking

We are starting to have a few projects that have a design where a web server needs access to services/devices (think database connections and specialized hardware) that are on a local network. Instead of having users open up ports to the public internet, we are using a small program that establishes a connection from inside their network to connect to those devices and then establish a persistent connection that the server can use to request information from that program.

EDIT: Diagram

[image: Diagram of the description]

I've thought of a few terms, but I wasn't sure if there is a generally accepted term for such a program

- Agent: This one seems kind of intuitive, but it seems like it means [something else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_agent).
- Proxy: Maybe, I typically think of a client connecting to a proxy, not the other way around.
- Service: This indicates it's a long running process that does something in the background, but nothing specific about communication.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall to me.  Or perhaps a proxy server.

Comment: [The user guide for AWS VPN](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html) contains a lot of terminology similar to your situation. However, they also use words for meanings that are somewhat different from the typical public usage of these words. Perhaps you can consult a few technical terminology sources and decide what definitions to use.

Comment: I think the term is Trojan Horse, or simply Trojan.

Comment: I do not understand the communication relationship between the nodes from your description. You have a web server, devices and users. Who is requesting from whom and where are they all? A picture may help.

Comment: @ArTs, it's not malware. :P The software performs very specific functions and must be configured locally and pointed to the central server.

Comment: @duckbrain if the program **acts in behalf of the device as a client** of the server (agency) then it's an agent. Like a browser user agent, but in this case the *users* are devices. If it's your server who acts like client of the remote program, then you have reversed the natural order of the client-server applications. In that case, what you have are embedded servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there is an official or defacto term for this but some possible descriptive options are:

- Delegate
- Delegate agent
- Proxy delegate
- Attorney

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I hadn't considered the use of "delegate". I realize there may not be an answer to my question, marking this as the accepted answer unless someone can find a reference to a term that's used widely elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the term 'worker' applies in your case, even though (to the best of my knowledge) it's generally used to describe software sub-tasks.